# Django Admin Drop down selections

Tags: django, django-admin

I use the django admin for updating various data on the MySQL database.  I use the basic django admin for this.  When entering in new data, I would like to be able to have it so people can only select from a few options to enter in new text data.

For example:
The table holds colors, so instead of letting the admin person (data entry individual in our case) just enter in anything into the text box, how can I get the django admin to only give them several options to choose from?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be done via the model field argument [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
myfield = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=[('green', 'green'), ('red', 'red')])
```

The only problem with this is that if you already have a value in the database that doesn't match one of these, django might just default it to one of the choices.

If that's a problem and you want to preserve those values, I might override the admin form and either only supply the `ChoiceField` on add operations or dynamically add whatever is in the DB as one of the valid choices.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    MY_CHOICES = [('green', 'green'), ('red', 'red')]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.instance.id:
           CHOICES_INCLUDING_DB_VALUE = [(self.instance.field,)*2] + self.MY_CHOICES
           self.fields['my_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices=CHOICES_INCLUDING_DB_VALUE)
       

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

Comment: I use it with floats: myfield = models.FloatField(choices=[('1.0', '1')] and get a message ("no correct selection 1.0") when using the dropdown in the admin edit.

Comment: Is this still good for django 2.1?  More recent answers about creating the drop down form field uses querysets in the forms module.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to define a "models.CharField" field type in your model

```
your_choices = (
        ('1', u'yello'),
        ('2', u'red'),
        ('3', u'black'),
    )

types = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=your_choices, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then in "admin.py" you should add this new field in your custom admin class like below.

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('types', )

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```